# Callkit: Muting first VOIP call before holding it and accepting VOIP second call also mutes the second call

Tags: ios, voip, callkit

We have a voip calling app which supports multiple calls at the same time. Problem is, if a user is on 1st voip call, mutes it and then holds it to accept 2nd voip call, the 2nd voip call does not have an outgoing audio. This means, it appears as if the 2nd voip call has been muted. Incoming audio works properly.

Is this working as expected with Callkit?